# How to specify an address in a Google Maps Directions API URL

Tags: google-maps

How do you specify an address in a Google Maps Web Services Directions API URL? The [Maps Web Services page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/#BuildingURLs) states

> Converting a URL that you receive from user input is sometimes tricky. For example, a user may enter an address as "5th&Main St." Generally, you should construct your URL from its parts, treating any user input as literal characters.

However this isn't very clear. There are no examples and I haven't been able to find any on the web. Does this mean that, for the given example, "5th&Main St." the following valid?

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?destination=5th%26Main+St.&sensor=true
```

If not, what would be the correct conversion?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: the conversion in your example is correct

Comment: I think I understand. The trickiness that's implied in the quote is that the & could be misinterpreted as an argument separator if it's just passed through as is. That is, not _converted_ properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per my understanding, you are looking for **`URI encode`**.

**In Javascript:**

> **`encodeURI`** is used to encode a string with special characters including
>   foreign language.

**Example:**

```
var address =  "5th&Main St.";
var encodedAddress = encodeURI(address);
```

then pass the encodedAddress in the google maps API.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?destination=encodedAddress&sensor=true
```

A small list of symbol equivalent encoding ([**Percent encoding**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)):

```
space   %20
!       %21
"       %22
#       %23
$       %24
%       %25
&       %26     // this what happended in your case
'       %27
(       %28
)       %29
```

Once I faced an issue, whild doing **`geocoding via C#`**.

Where I did a similar URI encoding using **`HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`** for address and then passed it to the Google API as I mentioned in above.  Each language has its own encoding technique, yet the output is same.

Hope you understand.

Comment: I'm actually programming in iOS, so the equivalent method would be NSString's stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding.I'm clear on it now. Thanks!

Comment: @Phil Oh, your doing in iOS.  Glad to here that I was able to help.  Thanks for sharing it :)